# Edit sidebar items in first-level categories

Tags: magento-1.8, category, sidebar

I am using magento 1.8 and I want to customize sidebar items in first-level categories. for example, I don't want the filters in first-level category page, But it should be in the lower level categories. Is there anyway to implement this?

Comment: if product is display on first level category then filter will display . if you display sub category with images then filter will not display

Comment: tnx, I set the category display mode to just static block, but the filters are still there! and filters are just one of them, I want to delete some of other items too.

Comment: still I am confused you can filter means attributes if you don't want filter in layered navigation then you can manage at attribute level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty simple to manage from Admin section of Magento. In `Catalog >> Manage Categories >> Select Category >> Display Settings` you will see one section named `Is Anchor`

Now if `Is Anchor is set to No`, the navigation filter will not be displayed. If `Is Anchor is set to Yes`, navigation filter will be displayed.

In your case, I think what you will be trying to achieve is when clicked on first level category the subcategories will be displayed with no filters.

To remove filter from top level category, you have to simply make the `Is Anchor to No` for that category.

For rest of the child categories make it `Yes`

Hope it helps!!